# Can I conquer the world?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Using Embark Everywhere is there a way to wipe out all other civilizations and have dorfs take over the world?

I hate those damned tree hugging elves, and those sick necrophiliac necromancer scum, and those dirty stinking goblins, and...

Edit:
Oh, I don't want to remove the sap suckers and the corpse abusers.

I want to murder them all, permanently, in the most brutal possible way.
(Is that wrong?)

Comment: Sounds like we need a new version to be released... the "@#$% the world" release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the current version of Dwarf Fortress, nothing happens in the world post-world gen.

This means (among other things), that civilizations cannot go extinct, animals won't repopulate, and towns will not change "ownership".

While Toady One (DF's developer) has expressed an interest in the ability to send your dwarven military out to assist in wars, battles, etc, nothing of the sort is currently achievable in-game.

So, sure, you can kill everything wherever you embark... but they won't acknowledge the fact that you've conquered them.

If you're more interested in a world without elves and necromancers, your better bet would be to tweak the world-gen parameters instead.

Comment: Sucks, but at least they can be murdered. Now back to my search for the most brutal method of execution ever invented...

Comment: @KillEmAll I suggest Magma.

Comment: It's a leading choice. We need to invent a "slow acting" version.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't do so in Fortress Mode, it's (technically) possible in adventure mode to kill everything.

**ERRYTHANG**

Comment: I don't want to kill everything, but I'll have to look into that. I mean, the inferior races and scum like the tree @#$%ers and corpse !@#$ers need to be forced into extinction, that's all. Especially those nasty necros - a foul bunch of reprobates.